# How to manage files and folder in Android 11 maintaining backwards-compatibility

Tags: android, file

I need to make my application compatible with android versions greater than 29 (Android 11+).
Currently I create a folder tree with the following code:

```
   public void createFolder() {
        try {
            ArrayList<File> listDir = new ArrayList<>();
            listDir.add(new File(MAIN_FOLDER));
            listDir.add(new File(CONFIG_FOLDER_ROOT));
            listDir.add(new File(PDF_FOLDER));
            listDir.add(new File(THUMB_FOLDER));
            listDir.add(new File(LOGS_FOLDER));
            listDir.add(new File(ARCHIVE_FOLDER));
            listDir.add(new File(ZOMBIE_FOLDER));
            listDir.add(new File(DATASHEET_FOLDER));

            for (int i = 0; i < listDir.size(); i++) {
                if (!listDir.get(i).exists()) {
                    if (listDir.get(i).mkdirs()) {
                        //Creo il file .incarichi
                        if (listDir.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(".Data") == 0) {
                            File fileIncarichi = new File(listDir.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), ASSIGNMENT_FILE);
                            if (!fileIncarichi.exists()) {
                                fileIncarichi.createNewFile();
                            }
                        }

                        //Creo il file .warning
                        if (listDir.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(".Logs") == 0) {
                            File fileIncarichi = new File(listDir.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), WARNING_FILE);
                            if (!fileIncarichi.exists()) {
                                fileIncarichi.createNewFile();
                            }
                            File fileConfig = new File(listDir.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), CONFIG_FILE);
                            if (!fileConfig.exists()) {
                                fileConfig.createNewFile();
                            }
                        }

                        //Creo i file .nomedia
                        File fileMedia = new File(listDir.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), ".nomedia");
                        if (!fileMedia.exists()) {
                            fileMedia.createNewFile();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            wil.WriteFile("1)FilesUtilities - Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

These are examples of the variables I pass to the "newFile()" functions:

```
public final static String MAIN_FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.MYAPP";
public final static String THUMB_FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.MYAPP/.Thumbs";
```

To maintain compatibility with new android versions I have inserted in the manifest and right now everything is working fine:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I received a notice via the play store that by May 5 I have to adapt my app so that it is compliant to the new policies, so I started to read up on how to make the app compatible with all versions of android, but I have some doubts on how to proceed.

Keeping in mind that I cannot create "custom" folders, could it be enough to create my directories directly in a public folder such as "Download, Documents" or is it necessary to completely change the procedures for creating and accessing files using "media store" or the "store access framework"?

Comment: Why not use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` as your root?

Comment: I need that the files that are created by the application "survive" even after uninstalling the application moreover, I must not have any space limitations. Would this solution allow me to get what I ask for?

Comment: "I need that the files that are created by the application "survive" even after uninstalling the application" -- why? You are actively trying to hide them from the user. Why does the *user* want a bunch of hidden files to remain around after uninstalling your app?

Comment: Right, the premise is missing. This one that I am developing is an app intended for a private audience, specifically for users of a company who use company-owned devices. The app takes care of the generation of documentation, if the app is uninstalled before the files are sent to the server, it is necessary to be able to recover them manually

Comment: Android is not designed for your scenario. What is beneficial to you and your audience is not necessarily beneficial to the rest of the 2.5 billion Android device users. If your app happens to be a device admin or device owner app, there might be other storage options, though I am not aware of any. I do not know of any location that your app can both read and write, using filesystem APIs, that survives uninstallation.

Comment: Wait a minute, right now the app works exactly the way I want, the files and directories are created correctly in a hidden folder at the same level as the shared folders (eg downloads, documents, etc), the problem is that the new release of android (10+) is it necessary adjust the code as it will no longer be possible to set it in the manifest requestLegacyExternalStorage = true

Comment: "is it necessary adjust the code as it will no longer be possible to set it in the manifest requestLegacyExternalStorage = true" -- correct. AFAIK, it will is necessary for you to adjust your code.  I do not know of any location that your app can both read and write, using filesystem APIs, that survives uninstallation.

Comment: @CommonsWare android WAS designed for this scenario.  Google just broke it badly in 11/10.  perhaps in a release or two they will revert to previous functionality. It's not our job to apologize for Google's choices but to advocate for what we want changed.

Answer (score 1):

Write your files in the classic way to a subdirectory of the public Documents folder.

They will survive.

But not reachable by classic file means (unless your app has 'all files access') but with SAF.

Comment: I have already tried to change the folder destination, eg. "donwload", but when I go to delete from the manifest android:requestLegacyExternalStorage, the folders are no longer created

Comment: You used an Android 11 device? Requesting legacy external storage yes or no should not have effect if you use an Android 11 device.

Comment: `eg. "donwload",` Do you mean the public `Download`folder?

Comment: Sorry for the typo "Download" and yes, I mean the public folder

Comment: You did not rect on my other remarks: any reason?